# How to find largest difference between two text files?

Tags: git-diff

So I'm trying to debug two large execution logs with 500000 lines each, there are minor/irrelevant differences between them; but I only want to obtain the line with the biggest difference between them.

I've been using `git diff`, but I don't know what option I would use to do this.

If there is a better tool, please let me know of a suggestion.